# Lower-bound on comparison-based sorting of n values in the range 1 to k

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Can we do better than O(n lg n) running time for a comparison-based algorithm when all of the values are in the range 1 to k, where k < n.

Counting sort and radix sort are not comparison-based algorithms and are disallowed. By a decision tree analysis, it seems like there are k^n possible permutations. There are 2^h leaves, so it should be possible to solve the problem in O(n lg k) time **with a comparison-based sorting algorithm**.

Please do not give a non-comparison based sorting algorithm for solving this problem, all sorting must be based on comparisons between two elements. Thanks!

Comment: Good question, actually. I really hope it's not homework... is it?

Comment: fyi - I think the number of permutations is n!/(a!b!...) where a! is the number of 1s, b! is the number of 2s, etc.

Comment: I don't think you get can to O(n lg k).  Although there are only k possible values, you still have n elements that need to be compared. Of course, I may be missing something: it's been a VERY long time since I did algorithm time analysis.

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question ? It's not practical enough to be an actual problem.

Answer (score 8):

It may easily be done in the bound you specified.  Build a binary tree of k leaves and include a count value on each leaf.  Processing each element (adding it or bumping the count) will be O(lg k) if one uses a suitable balancing algorithm, so doing all of them will be O(n lg k).  Reconstituting the list will then be O(n).

Comment: Re: Armen, no this isn't homework.

Re: supercat, that's what first came to mind, I think that works.

Comment: @user666866- Technically speaking, this isn't a comparison sort because it counts up the number of times each element appears.  If you're allowed to count elements, there are much faster ways of solving this problem.

Comment: @templatetypedef - It's a totally legitimate comparison based sort.  The only operation he uses on the elements in the input are comparisons and moves/copies.  He isn't doing anything fancy like indexing by them, or inspecting their structure and branching on higher or lower order bits.  You can imagine that instead of 'counting' in the leaves of a binary search tree, he copies them into a list at the leaf of the BST.  After he is done building the tree, he walks the tree in order, outputs all of the items in the leaf, and is done.

Comment: @rrenaud- Ah, that's a very valid point.  Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, if you insist you want comparisons.

You have **k** elements. So, keep a tree structure that will hold all the elements.

Go over the list of items, each time add the item to the tree. If the item is already in the tree, just increment the counter in that node. (or if you want the actual items you can keep a list in each node)

The tree will have no more than **k** items.

in the end, go over the tree in an inorder way, and add the items back in the right order (while adding the amount that are in the node's counter).

Complexity: **O(nlogk)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use an array of size k. (Without comparisons)

Each cell i will contain a list.
go over the original array, put every item in the list of the right cell.

Go over the the second array, and pull them out, put them back in the right order.

**O(n)**

Comment: it is basically bucket/count sort, which the OP explicitly excluded from possible solutions

Comment: not comparison, you just put item i in A[i] ... straightforward, no comparisons.